# How to debug django ajax function when using djangorestframework decorator?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

How to debug ajax function when using djangorestframework decorator.

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def authfb(request):
    require_more_data = True
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.data['fb_first_name']
        last_name = request.data['fb_last_name']
        fb_picture = request.data['fb_picture']
        fb_friends_number = request.data['fb_friends_number']
        fb_username = request.data['fb_username']
        fb_id = int(request.data['fb_id'])
        fb_link = request.data['fb_link']
        username = fb_username.replace(' ', '')

        # print(username)
        password = '112358'
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)


    return Response(request.data)
```

Example of code. Django doesn't tell about any errors, when calling view functions through ajax request. This makes me using print and searching the wrong line manually and still leaves no idea what exactly is wrong. How to debug it, how to make django log errors as usual?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging ajax functions, it's preferable to return a response data (json formatted data, for more transparency) from the Django view, which could be logged in the console from the ajax error method. Then, the universal methods always come in handy for debugging any requests (print statements, try & except statements)

I'd recommend using try statements more often, as it is much appreciated by experienced coders and also easy to debug.

For a simple example:

```
def authfb(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        msg = "Unknown error"
        status = False
        try:
            #do something
            msg = "Everything's​ Goood"
            status = True
        except Exception as e:
            msg = str(e)
    return JsonResponse ({'status':status, 'msg':msg, 'anything':'that_thing'})
```

Although, this is only my suggestion, there are many other much better ways.
From my opinion, there is no right way for debugging, every way is right way in its own perspective.

Hope you got what you were looking for.

Comment: response is ok, there is response. in my case data or request data. but it doesn't help in django debugging. for example when you create new instance of model and there is one field not inserted

Comment: If each field is required, then adding model meta field options of not null constraint would make some help in django debugging.